# If $A^2=-I$, Prove that $\det{A}=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A^2=-I$ , where $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ and which contains real entries only and $I$ is identity matrix. Then how can we prove that $\det(A)=1$?.

I could prove that $n$ should be an even integer. But could not proceed to prove that $\det(A)$ can take only $1$, finding out few matrices which satisfies such properies (of small order) also verifies the given statement that the determinant is only $1$ and not $-1$.

Can anyone help with a hint ?

Comment: I assume $n$ is even?

Comment: $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2=\det(-I)=-1$, so maybe your question's wrong

Comment: @Shuchang: $\det(-I)=(-1)^n.$ Hence user7530's comment.

Comment: @user7530: Why did u remove the post?

Comment: @CameronBuie Oh, what was I thinking. Thanks

Comment: note that det(A) is the product of all roots of characteristic polynomia(n even). now, what are the possible roots? does real coefficients help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$, with eigenvector $v$.

Then 
$$v^HA^2v = v^H(-I)v.$$
What can you conclude about $\lambda$?

Now use the fact that the eigenvalues of a real matrix must come in complex conjugate pairs, and that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Got it . The eigenvalues are $i$ and $-i$ and the determinant is $1$.Thanks